# Unable to get the same curve as question with parametric equations

Tags: trigonometry, graphing-functions, curves, parametric

my given task is to write a parametric equation to create this spiral curve with the parameters, $t \in [0, 1]$.

[image]

my answer is

$x = 0.8\cdot t\cdot\cos(-3.5\pi t)$ 
$y = 0.8 \cdot t\cdot\sin(-3.5\pi t)\ +\ 0.2$

However, I am unable to get the same curve. As you can see, the question's curve goes into the negative region of y-axis. But my curve doesn't. Also, I don't seem to touch the 0.6 point in y-axis.

[image]

I am using Desmos to test with my equations, but I can't seem to increase the "inner radius" of the spiral curve.

Could someone please point me out on what I am missing out please?

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/odaxzim8uc

Comment: Your curve doesn't pass through $(0, 0.6) $ as in the question.

Comment: yes, thank you, I notice that, I think I am using the wrong spiral equation but I am not sure. In my question, I am using spiral equation given in my lecture notes. I am currently googling up more on spiral equations now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a first round of $2\pi$ the parameter $t$ goes from $0$ to $0.5$ and the radius increase from $0.2$ to $0.6$, so
\begin{align}
x = \left(0.2+\frac{0.6-0.2}{0.5}t\right)\sin(4\pi t),\\
y = \left(0.2+\frac{0.6-0.2}{0.5}t\right)\cos(4\pi t),\\
\end{align}
with $t\in[0,1].$

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What about

$$r(\theta)=1.0-0.4\frac{\theta-\pi/2}{2\pi}$$ for $\theta \in [\pi/2,\pi/2 +4\pi]$ in polar coordinates? That you can transform into cartesian coordinates on the interval $[0,1]$ if you wish.